# Building a device that lights an LED once a minute

Tags: led, timer, bom

I'm a complete noob in electronics. I want to build a simple battery-operated device that lights an LED for one second, once every minute. What do I need to buy to build it?

Comment: A book on timer circuits would be a good start.

Comment: To be honest, if you're looking for low power (or even really if you aren't), a microcontroller is a good solution. Starting to learn to use one is a good idea generally.

Comment: I can think of at least 10 completely different circuits to achieve that kind of thing. The choice will narrow down as you add more requirements like, what kind of battery can be used, how long does it have to run on the batteries, how accurate should the timing be (is 50 seconds instead of a minute OK)?

Comment: I agree that a microcontroller is a viable solution, however an ICM7555 (CMOS version of 555 timer) based circuit might be more "educational" from an electronics point of view.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'd argue that depends on what you want to teach! Wanting to teach sawtooth signals and thresholding, RC \$\tau\$ and analog electronics, sure. Wanting to teach digital electronics, system coding and practical hardware design, I'd go for the microcontroller.

Comment: As a learning experience it would be great to do both, a 555 and a microcontroller based design.  Then compare the advantages and disadvantages of each.

Comment: I know I phrased that with a tendency – but I actually think the time is ripe to consider digital electronics the "basic" thing and analog electronics the "advanced" thing, though that has traditionally be taught in the "analog first, digital later" order.

Comment: Oh yeah? Are you going to teach digital filters first then analogue filters later? @anyonewhocares

Comment: As a current student who is learning electronics, in response to @MarcusMüller I'd say they should keep teaching analog first. That is where you get a lot of fundamental knowledge from and to be honest, that is lacking a LOT these days. It should be taught first. Tutors aren't very good at teaching it any more unfortunately. I could go on but this isn;t the place! But as for the OPs question, it depends what ou want to learn from it. I would go for the 555 approach as a beginner

Comment: The biggest challenge here is choosing one of the many reasons to close this question...

Comment: @Andyaka guess what: I'm *way* more proficient with digital filters than with analog ones, though I've definitely first learned how to do Bode plots for the passive analog variety; coming from the DSP side, you really don't *have* to teach analog before digital filters (though you definitely have to introduce the transition between these worlds including the inevitably analog anti-imaging/aliasing filters). and, having *studied this shit*, I'd agree: in an EE program, starting with the analog filters makes sense, since you also start with linear electrical networks. But for anyone who's not1/2

Comment: … planning to do signal processing but do simple control jobs like what OP's facing, I'd argue that either way, there's lots of magic happening that you won't understand at first, no matter whether you're going the 555 or the MCU route.

Comment: So, @Andyaka, yes, I'm confident one can teach about digital filters meaningfully without talking about analog ones first. In fact, planning to do that with a group of amateurs in less than 2 weeks. The signal theory is slightly different, but if you care about the signal and not about implementation, it really doesn't matter if you swallow the "spectrum's periodic, since we're discrete" pill first.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think it can be done D first even with filters - I was just trying to be naughty. The bigger question is.... which one is a subset of the other lol.

Comment: A key question will be how accurate your time needs to be.  If it matters, using a cheap MCU to count multiple cycles of a crystal (or at least ceramic resonator) will be repeatable, while an RC timer circuit is probably going to need tuning each time it is built.